# Run a function or a block of code whenever a value of variable changes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and I want to perform a specific task whenever a value of variable gets changed. I have tried flutter hooks package but I don`t want to use any external packages.

I am also not using TextFormField so onChanged feature can't be used.

Comment: If it's a global variable or a member variable on a class you control, you can just provide [a setter function](https://dart.dev/language/methods#getters-and-setters) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueNotifier`, e.g

```dart
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
```

to listen the changes

```dart
  _counter.addListener(() { //make sure to `_counter.dispose()`
      print(_counter.value); // you can run your function here
    });
```

And for the UI, you can use `ValueListenableBuilder`

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: _counter,
  builder: (BuildContext context, dynamic value, Widget? child) {
    return Text(
      '$_counter',
    );
  },
),
```